# Netsuite saved search inventory counts

Tags: netsuite, inventory-management

I am new to NetSuite. I have set up Calculated Inventory Counts and want to set up some reports based on the counts we have done.

I am attempting to set up a saved search for Inventory Count Transactions so that I can see which individual items were counted during a range of days, how many adjustments were made as a result, etc.

Unfortunately, I don't see Inventory Count as one of the criteria under Transactions.

I would be surprised if this has not come up befre, but I have searched and not found any relevant answers

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Criteria name is "Type" - then select Inventory Count from the list that appears.

Comment: This is helpful.  I can now return a list of counts for a specified date range.  Is there anyway to return a list of the individual items counted?

Comment: See my answer to your other question.